# Why does my recursion not return to previous pointer?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am working on an assignment in which we must create a 20-questions type game from a binary search tree. We read the tree in from a text file that is formatted like this:

```
Does it walk on 4 legs?
Does it fly?
*centipede?
Is it an insect?
*bird?
*butterfly?
Does it purr?
Does it howl?
*mouse?
*dog?
*cat?
```

Later, I am going to allow the user to add to this list. At the moment, however, I am unable to accurately read the list into a binary search tree. I have set it up so that (I think) it will use recursion and return to the previous "current" node pointer when it ends a loop of the function. Currently, however, the current node pointer remains the same.

The below function is passed a vector of the strings from the text file.

```
string line;
string guess;
bool start = true;

void buildTree(vector<string> gameData, Node* current, int &counter)
{
    //fill node with question or answer
    //recursive:
    //  add to the left until we encounter an asterisk
    //  add to the right
    line = gameData[counter];

    //if a question
    if (line[0] != '*')
    {
        if (current->getData().empty())
        {
            current->setData(line);
            cout << current->getData() << endl;
        }
        if (!start)
        {
            //if noChild is empty AND current isn't a guess, go to noChild
            if ((current->getNo()->getData().empty()) 
                && (current->isGuess() == false))
            {
                current = current->getNo();
            }
            //otherwise, go to yes
            else {
                current = current->getYes();
            }
        }
        while (counter < gameData.size())
        {
            if (!start) { counter++; }
            start = false;
            buildTree(gameData, current, counter);
        }
    }
    //if a guess
    else
    {
        //if data is full, go to no
        if (current->getData().empty() == false)
        {
            current = current->getNo();
        }
        //otherwise, go to yes
        else 
        {
            //current = current->getYes();
            for (int i = 1; i < line.size(); i++)
            {
                guess.push_back(line[i]);
            }
            current->setData(guess);
            guess.clear();
            cout << current->getData() << endl;
            counter++;
            current->setGuess(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion and global variables is a very unpleasant combination.

Comment: @molbdnilo My teacher mentioned something to me about recursion and global variables before, but moved on before explaining it thoroughly. Which variables should I try moving to where?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, just don't use global variables at all. Look at the scope they're really used in, and move them there.

Comment: @Fehler Don't use any global variables whatsoever. Use local variables, (non-reference) parameters, and return values.

Comment: OK, I'll work on that. Thanks @molbdnilo

Comment: @molbdnilo, I guess I'm stupid, but I'm still confused what exactly to change. I think my vector of strings and counter can stay global because they stay constant or increase constantly.

I understand my current pointer has an issue, but I don't know how to fix it. If I don't declare a pointer Node outside my function, how can I access the newly created ones? Should I be returning a pointer instead?

Comment: @Fehler Yes, you should return a pointer (but you shouldn't pass one), and you should not use any loops. You should not use globals "by default" but only when it's necessary.